# Keyboad key wrongly interpreted by X server. How should I go about investigating this?

Tags: linux, x11, keyboard-shortcuts, input

I have Kubuntu 19.10, running i3wm with Plasma, on my ASUS FX505DT.
I noticed weird behaviour today. Pressing `Fn + F9` on my keyboard is registered as `keycode 33 "p"`, which should actually be `XF86Display`.
Below is what `xev` returns:

```
KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0x642, subw 0x0, time 613368, (94,126), root:(965,587),
    state 0x40, keycode 33 (keysym 0x70, p), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (70) "p"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (70) "p"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0x642, subw 0x0, time 613369, (94,126), root:(965,587),
    state 0x40, keycode 33 (keysym 0x70, p), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (70) "p"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0x642, subw 0x0, time 614051, (94,126), root:(965,587),
    state 0x40, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: False
```

Also, weirdly enough, even KeyRelease of `Fn` is being interpreted as `keycode 133`.

This is the issue that I'm facing. *Kindly help me in investing this issue so I can reach towards a solution*.

Comment: What's the output of `xmodmap -pke | grep 133` ?

Comment: @SHW It's `keycode 133 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L`

Comment: does any other key produce `keycode 133`? ... perhaps your keyboard is failing in some way ... key stuck down, two keys stuck together, two keys shorted electrically, etc.

Comment: @jsotola Yes, it is produced by Super_L.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing, I've found out that my laptop's(ASUS FX505DT) keyboard doesn't have separate `scancode` for `Fn` + `F9`. Instead, this combination simply reverts to `Super` + `p` key combination. That's why this issue was arising for me.